# AngularJS DOM Manipulation through Directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Currently I have a working angular app .... It works but im doing some DOM manipulation stuff in my controller rather than in a directive like i should. The problem is and my question becomes, HOW do i implement this type of functionality properly using directives??

A simple example is:

```
<div id="container1"></div>

<button type="button" ng-click="changeSize(1)">Small</button>
<button type="button" ng-click="changeSize(2)">Medium</button>
<button type="button" ng-click="changeSize(3)">Large</button>
```

That would essentially call the changeSize method in my controller which give or take looks like this:

```
$scope.changeVideoSize = function(size) {
    switch (size) {

        case 1:
            resizeDiv("container1", "320px" , "240px");
        case 2:
            resizeDiv("container1", "640px" , "480px");
        case 3:
            resizeDiv("container1", "1280px" , "960px");
    }
}
function resizeDiv(id, width, height) {
    var elem = document.getElementById(id);
    elem.style.height = height;
    elem.style.width = width;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a directive that looks something like

```
angular.module('myApp.directives', []).
    directive('changeSize', [function() {
        return function(scope, elm, attrs) {

            function resizeDiv(id, width, height) {
                var elem = document.getElementById(id);
                elem.style.height = height;
                elem.style.width = width;
            }

            elm.bind("click", function(){
                  switch (attrs.size) {
                        case 1:
                            resizeDiv("container1", "320px" , "240px");
                        case 2:
                            resizeDiv("container1", "640px" , "480px");
                        case 3:
                            resizeDiv("container1", "1280px" , "960px");
                    }
            });
        };
  }]);
```

and then change your markup to this:

```
<div id="container1"></div>

<button type="button" change-size size="1">Small</button>
<button type="button" change-size size="2">Medium</button>
<button type="button" change-size size="3">Large</button>
```

Comment: To make it more dynamic would it be appropriate to do <button type="button" change-size size="1" elem="container1">Small</button>

Comment: yeah, I like that even better!

Answer (score 0):

@MDiesel, your example demonstrate the user of a directive, but I think it has some flaws.
I believe a directive should be used when doing DOM manipulation, or for a reusable component that has an API.

Assuming the use case is pure DOM manipulation that will not be reused, I'd write the following:

```
angular.module('myApp.directives', []).
    directive('resizeable', [function() {
        return {
            // Might be better to use a URL instead for better readability\maintainability.
            template: '<div id="container1"></div>' +
                      '<button type="button" ng-click="changeSize(1)">Small</button>' +
                      '<button type="button" ng-click="changeSize(2)">Medium</button>' +
                      '<button type="button" ng-click="changeSize(3)">Large</button>',
            link: function(scope, element) {
                scope.changeSize = function (size) {
                     var containerElement = element.find('#container1');
                     switch (size) {
                         case 1:
                             containerElement.width(320);
                             containerElement.height(240);
                         case 2:
                             containerElement.width(640);
                             containerElement.height(480);
                         case 3:
                             containerElement.width(1280);
                             containerElement.height(960);
                     }
                }
            }                
        }
    ]);
```

1. Directive is now self contained, you shouldn't use document to change the DOM, it misses the point of a directive.
2. ng-click is better than listening to click event yourself, it makes the template more self explanatory.

If the use case is to make this directive reusable and might contain many elements, then it's another case. Let me know and I'll write about that one.

Comment: So I mostly have this example working. The issue I have is that I do not want to create the div "container1" in the directive as it resides elsewhere on the page. That being said I have put some logging in to make sure i get into the changesize function and that size is passed in correctly ... but my dom elements never actually resize. Im starting to wonder if its because im not creating the dom elements in the directive as you showed above.