# angularjs dom manipulation based on button click

Tags: angularjs, dom, angularjs-directive

basically i want to change the attribute value based on the button i clicked,
these are the two buttons

```
<button ng-click="fn(a)"></button>
<button ng-click="fn(b)"></button>
```

and then i have a prebuilt directive who takes value as input,

```
<div directive-name="" id="abc"></div>
```

if i click on first button,i want the value of directive based on button clicked.

What i did earlier;

```
$scope.go = function(data){
if(data==a){
var b =  document.querySelector( 'div' );
b.setAttribute("directive-name","value");
}
else{}
}
```

here the problem is that it is selecting the first div of document and setting attribute value for that.
I also tried to pass it with id like

```
var b = angular.element(document.querySelector('#abc'));
```

I also saw some custom directives to do so, but they are not working

[AngularJS DOM Manipulation through Directives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23414145/angularjs-dom-manipulation-through-directives)

If possible provide me a demo in plunkr or fiddle

and also if i want to change css property of div based on button clicked

Thanks in advance

Comment: its $scope.fn = function(data){}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this.
Assign the directive-name value to a `$scope.variable` and then use `variable` as the value in HTML.

HTML - 1:

```
<button ng-click="go(a)"></button>
<button ng-click="go(b)"></button>
```

HTML - 2:

```
<div directive-name="{{directive}}" id="abc"></div>
```

JS:

```
$scope.go = function(data){
  if(data==a){
    $scope.directive = "directive-1";
  }else if(data==b){
    $scope.directive = "directive-2";
  }
}
```

To assign class name to div you can define other `$scope.classVar` and then use that in HTML like below:

```
<div directive-name="{{directive}}" id="abc" ng-class="classVar"></div>
```

I hope this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

This should work, (you had some errors in your code):-

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {

  $scope.fn = function(data,id) {
    if (data == 'a') {
      var b = document.querySelector('#'+id);
      b.setAttribute("directive-name", "value");
    } else {
    }
  
}
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>

<body>

  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <div directive-name="" id="abc"></div>
    <button ng-click="fn('a','abc')">A</button>
  </div>
```

Comment: one more thing i would like to add is that, i am using ui routing ,when i click on a button along with ui-sref it also changing the state which contain the directive whose attribute need to be set

Comment: @AnkurChauhan instead of using ui-sref use $state.go after setattribute inside controller to change state

Answer (score 0):

**"Basically I want to change the attribute value based on the button I clicked."**

You can do this by changing the attribute value the angular way, referencing a property of `$scope` or the controller instance in your template. When clicking a button, set the variable to the value you require to be passed to your directive.

**Note:** When you pass a value into your [`ngClick`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick) directive, you need to pass it as a string unless `a` and `b` are declared as properties of `$scope`.

Here's a basic example:

```js
// app.js
(function() {

  'use strict';

  angular.module('app', []);

})();

// main.controller.js
(function() {

  'use strict';

  angular.module('app').controller('MainController', MainController);

  MainController.$inject = ['$scope'];

  function MainController($scope) {

    $scope.fn = fn;

    function fn(data) {
      // set the value so it's accessable in the view
      // therefore we can pass it into our directive
      $scope.myVar = data;
    }

  }

})();

// directive-name.directive.js
(function() {

  'use strict';

  angular.module('app').directive('directiveName', directiveNameDirective);

  function directiveNameDirective() {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      scope: {
        directiveName: '='
      },
      template: '<span>directiveName: {{ directiveName }}</span>'
    };
  }

})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app">

  <div ng-controller="MainController as MainCtrl">

    <!-- here we pass a and b as strings otherwise they get evaluated as variables -->
    <button ng-click="fn('a')">Set a</button>
    <button ng-click="fn('b')">Set b</button>

    <hr>

    <!-- here we pass myVar which is declared as a property of $scope when the fn function is called -->
    <div directive-name="myVar" id="abc"></div>

    <hr> myVar: {{ myVar }}

  </div>

</div>
```